# Is there a Java library for the Bitly API?

Tags: java, bit.ly

Is there a Java library for making [Bitly](http://bit.ly) requests?  I'm looking to both shorten links, and look up info on clicks, etc. of links.  Yes, I know it's a straight-forward [HTML API](http://bit.ly/apidocs) and I could just code directly to the HTML or write a library myself, but surely someone else has written such a library, and it would save me a couple of steps to use it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This looks promising: http://code.google.com/p/bitlyj/

Answer (score 0):

for the look up part i did it using php [Bitly-PHP](https://github.com/TareqBajjlay/Bitly-PHP) to get stats (FB, TW Clicks)